# Multiple configuration per package

Tags: laravel, oauth

I want to use several configs for one package. I use Laravel 5.1 with lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel package (I can't upgrade my environment due to customer restrictions). I want to use different oauth configurations for different routes in my application. How to implement this?

Or more general question: how to use multiple configs for package that doesn't allow it by default?

Comment: I guess you can try setting the configs in the middleware.